# How do I set the style.top property of an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I must fix a JavaScript source-code, which sets the style.top property of a div element depending upon an integer parameter of a function called index like this:

```
div.style.top = (index * 22 + 2)+"px";
```

For bigger values of index `(20, 21, 22,.... 53, 54,...)` the value of div.style.top is not accurate anymore, i.e. it becomes too big, while for small values ( i.e. `index < 10`) the value of div.style.top calculated like this is OK.
My idea was to use the already existing HTML element called checkbox, which is visually correct aligned, and take its style.top value like this:

```
div.style.top = checkbox.style.top
```

But checkbox.style.top is not defined, although the element checkbox is correctly displayed on the HTML page.

Is there some way to set the value of checkbox.style.top to be equal to the actual absolute position it takes, without knowing what this value is?

Comment: Without the actual code, it's hard to say anything. Please add the relevant CSS and HTML.

Comment: Click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: use `checkbox.offestTop` instead of `checkbox.style.top`

Comment: the part of the HTML content I am interested in is dynamically generated in an iframe using an Ajax call to a Java Backend,  so it would not be very easy to provide a minimal working example

Comment: Not easy? Programming is not always easy, you've to do some work too. You can easily copy-paste the related HTML and CSS from the Dev Tools, though.

Comment: Another (maybe more recommendable?) way is, that you learn how the [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) works, and then fix your secret code yourself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element.offsetTop;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) (per MDN):

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
var topPos = d.offsetTop;

if (topPos > 10) {
  // object is offset more
  // than 10 pixels from its parent
}
```